# How do I enable trash functionality on Samba shares?

Tags: samba, delete, trash

I have a successful samba server setup but it's rather annoying that when I delete a file I can only delete it permanently and not move it to the trash. So my question is, how do I enable trash functionality on a samba share? I'd prefer to get an explanation on how to do it by CLI since this setup is on Ubuntu Server 11.04 :)

The only article I found regarding this on the web is this tutorial for Red Hat:
http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/sambatrash.html

Please help me out here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this guide: [The Official Samba HOWTO](http://pl.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-HOWTO-Collection.pdf) to enable the recycle VFS module.

**Edit:**

Online version of the [section you need](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/VFS.html)

Have fun ;)

Comment: Thanks! The online document and this linked page helped me set this up:
http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/sambatrash.html

Comment: some guidance would have helped